# Does exists any popular iconset for most frequently used file types?

Tags: user-interface, graphics, icons

Does exists any big (big I mean hundreds of icons) iconset for most frequently file types available to download for free? I need to use this iconset to my Document Management System. More filetypes iconset is more better. Which iconset do you prefere for this usecase?

I mean especially file types(extensions) for base users (not focused to development), e.g.: doc, docx, ppt, pptx, xls, xlsx, odt, txt, avi, gif, jpg, png, pdf, mp3, mp4, mid...

Ideally in JPG, PNG or SVG format. 64x64 pixelx is for my usecase enough.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is possible to extract from linux icon sets.